# How to manage multi-packet sends with gsocket?

Tags: tcp, packet

I got a question regarding tcp/ip socket networking. Basically it is there: are there any parts of tcp/ip that I can leverage to help manage multi-packet sends. For example, I want to send a 100 mb binary file which would take something like 70-80 tcp packets. Meanwhile I have a relatively fast polling receive on the other side. Would my receive have to receive each packet it individually and "stitch" together the data packet by packet, looking for some size to be reached(it can look at the opcode and determine size) or is there some way to tell tcp to say "hey I'm sending 100 mb here, let them know when it is finished."

I am using glib's low level socket library (gsocket).

Answer (score 0):

When using a binary encoding like, say protocol buffers, you would wrap the actual payload by inserting a header that would include the information necessary to decode the payload on the other end.

Say appending 8 bytes where the first 4 signify the type of the encoded message and the second four indicate the length of the entire message.

On the receiving side you are then reading this header, that's part of the payload, to determine the message type and length of the message. This lets you combine multiple messages in one payload or split messages across packets and reliably recombine them.

Comment: with no familiarity with gsocket, I can't provide any code sample for how they exactly would go about calculating and appending a header to the payload they are sending.